# Puppet copy file if not empty

Tags: devops, puppet, configuration-management, puppet-enterprise

I have a requirement where I need to check for a file on the puppet master and copy it to the agent only if it is not empty.

I have the following so far:

```
  exec {
    'check_empty_file':
      provider => shell,
      command  => "test -s puppet:////path/to/puppetmaster/file",
      returns  => ["0", "1"],
  }

  if $check_empty_file == '0' {
    file {
      'file_name':
        path    => '/path/to/agent/file',
        alias   => '/path/to/agent/file',
        source  => "puppet:///path/to/puppetmaster/file",
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an `Exec` resource to perform the check, because you need to perform the evaluation during catalog building, and resources are not applied until after the catalog is built.  Moreover, the `test` command tests for the existence of a the specified *path*.  It does not know about URLs, and even if it did, it would be unlikely to recognize or handle the `puppet:` URL scheme.  Furthermore, there is no association whatever between resource titles and variable names.

To gather data at catalog building time, you're looking for a puppet [*function*](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.19/function.html).  It is not that hard to add your own custom function to Puppet, but you don't need that for your case -- the built-in [`file()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.19/function.html#file) function will serve your purpose.  It might look something like this:

```
$file_content = file('<module-name>/<file-name>')

if $file_content != '' {
  file { '/path/to/target/file':
    ensure  => 'file',
    content => $file_content,
    # ...
  }
}
```